# Spatial Joins - Intersect then non-joined Nearest

Tags: attribute-joins, proximity, intersect

Is there a tool to join by interest and then for those that are not joined, join by nearest - all in one calculation? If not, maybe this is a valid feature request, to combine these two tools together instead of having to run then separately?

Comment: isn't an intersecting feature also the nearest one?

Comment: That was my thought also. The intersection is somewhat redundant, unless a one-to-many relationship is desired.

Comment: Apologies for lack in clarification with the software; was thinking of QGIS. @JGH - wasn't aware of that "Intersecting feature also the nearest one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there are direct tool. However there are approaches that solve this.

there are 2 approaches:

- utilise [model builder](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm) in ArcGIS or QGIS, create your own tool, use the if conditional and everything. It is a GUI drag and drop algorithm builder and it is quite intuitive as long as you have those process back in mind.
- use python [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html), define the interest in a function (by distance? intersect? touches? etc...), and use [spatial join by nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html).

Comment: this is great, I actually never knew about the model builder. The alternative with Python is also a great answer, thank you!